# How to create a Custom Meta Box with Name/Value Admin User Input Fields?

Tags: custom-field, metabox, meta-value

I have researched many tutorials on how to create/add Custom Meta Boxes using the `add_meta_box()` Wordpress function. I can not find any example where the finished Meta Box has the option for an Admin User to input both **key/value**  pairs like [Custom_Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)?

EDIT: Removed plugin link URL as not enough rep points:

I want to add this capability to my own Custom Meta Boxes and to the WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress plugin's Meta Box fields.

To clarify, I want to create a Meta Box that Admin Users can add Name and Value to - like is shown in this image taken from the WP's own Custom Fields Meta Box :

[image]

Edit 19.06.14:

My understanding of `Custom Fields` was incorrect, when querying on the front end:

```
        printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', var_export( get_post_meta($post->ID,"my_custom_filed_key"), true ) );
```

I see that `my_custom_field_key` produces an index array:

```
array (
0 => 'val  1',
1 => 'val  2',
2 => 'val  3',
)
```

I suppose what I am trying to achieve is an associative array?

```
array (
'my key name 1' => 'my val 1',
'my key name 2' => 'my val 2',
'my key name 3' => 'my val 3',
)
```

Here is the `add_meta_box` function part of my code:

```
function my_meta_boxes($post) {
        add_meta_box(
            'my_meta',          // Unique ID
            esc_html__( 'Reviews', 'example' ), // Title
            'my_meta_box',  // Callback function
            'my-post',          // Admin page (or post type)
            'side',               // Context
            'default'             // Priority
        );
 }

/* Display the post meta box. */
function my_meta_box() { 
        wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'my_post_nonce' ); 

        $meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $meta['my_meta'] = maybe_unserialize($meta['my_meta'][0]);
        ?>
        <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr style="width:100%;">
                <td><textarea style="width:90%;" rows="1" name="my_meta[]"> <?php echo $meta['my_meta'][0] ?></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="width:100%;">
                <td><textarea style="width:90%;" rows="1" name="my_meta[]"> <?php echo $meta['my_meta'][1] ?></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="width:100%;">
                <td><textarea style="width:90%;" rows="1" name="my_meta[]"> <?php echo $meta['my_meta'][2] ?></textarea></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
<?php }
```

I am wondering if the `add_meta_box` [$callbacks_args](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Callback_args) would help me here, but I am yet to full understand it?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.   As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited out text from my post which may not have been needed and have added a visual image of the Name/Value fields I am trying to create. I hope that I am understood now?

Comment: I understand what you need now, but I don't know what you've tried yourself and what went wrong :-). You're unlikely to get any real help if you haven't tried it yourself.

Comment: Really? I see many examples where a poster receives 'real help' with less effort: [minimal post with help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595604/add-meta-key-and-meta-value-to-post-in-wordpress-programmatically) Not that I do not agree with the general benefits of self-help ;) I am looking in a new direction to try and achieve my goal - as per post edits.

Comment: @user1575949 Different sites have a different understanding and agreement of the minimum needed quality and prerequisites for questions. The one you are currently looking at has a very high expectation. Thanks for your edit and for respect for the expected quality.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering if that was the case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you understanding how forms work: They add to the `$_POST` array by a form fields `name` argument.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="Fooo!" />
```

would produce

```
$_POST (array) =>
    foo => Fooo!
```

while

```
<input type="text" name="foo[bar]" value="Bar." />
<input type="text" name="foo[baz]" value="Baz." />
```

would produce

```
$_POST (array) =>
    foo => (array) =>
        bar => Bar.
        baz => Baz.
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had thought it would be possible for an admin user to input text into the name attribute and the value attribute, then I would output both key and value of the input tag _blush_.